# How to pass system system properties from jruby to Rails server

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm running a local Rails server (WEBrick) via JRuby and want to test some code that will eventually be running on Torquebox.  I'm trying to access some custom Java system properties via `ENV_JAVA`.  These system properties will be available when running on Torquebox so to test my code locally, I'm passing in the system properties on the command line using the "-J" argument.
When I run just JRuby, everything works fine,  I can access my custom property.

```
C:\jruby\jruby-1.7.24\bin\jruby.exe -J-Dmy_prop=my_value -e "puts ENV_JAVA['my_prop']"
```

This simply prints "my_value" to output.

My problem is trying access these custom properties when running a local Rails server.  My command line to startup the local Rails server looks something like this:

```
C:\jruby\jruby-1.7.24\bin\jruby.exe -J-Dmy_prop=my_value C:\jruby\jruby-1.7.24\bin\rails s
```

When WEBrick starts up, my custom property `"my_prop"` is no longer in `ENV_JAVA`.  It looks like this is because inside the railties Rails::AppRailsLoader module, `exec_app_rails` simply replaces the current process with another one by calling the Kernel `exec` method and passing in the command arguments.

This does NOT keep the custom properties around.  Does anyone know how I can work around this?  I'm currently running Rails 4.2.6. It looks like in Rails 5 the module name changed to `Rails::AppLoader`.

Comment: no one?  wow I'm surprised that this hasn't come up before.  In the meantime, to work around this issue I had to edit the railties gem to make this work.  In gems lib/rails/app_rails_loader.rb, I had to change the exec_app_rails method which calls:
    `exec RUBY, exe, *ARGV`

to

    `exec RUBY, -D-Dmy_prop=my_value, exe, *ARGV`

Comment: putting code in comments is so painful...see below

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out a better(?) way to handle this.  Instead of:

```
exec RUBY, exe, *ARGV
```

I can do this:

```
custom_sys_props = {}
current_sys_props = ENV_JAVA.to_hash
default_sys_props = eval(%x(#{RUBY} -e "puts ENV_JAVA"))
current_sys_props.each {|k,v| custom_sys_props[k] = v if default_sys_props[k] != v }
jruby_props = []
custom_sys_props.each{|k,v| jruby_props << "-J-D#{k}=#{v}"}         
exec RUBY, *jruby_props, exe, *ARGV
```

Its ugly and really only works for JRuby, but I dont know of a better way to handle it.  Still a shame that this hasn't been addressed before

Answer (score 0):

After discussing with a colleague, turns out I can run my rails server by calling

```
jruby.exe -J-Dmy_prop=my_value script/rails
```

from within my project directory.  So I dont even need to run the rails.bat script.  Hope this helps someone